# how to display dynamic <img src> on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to make a website that allow users to input questions, and then the website will display some pictures related to user input

i tried to wrap the output in img src tag, however the output is simply a line of code instead of picture

```
<img src="path/reply.jpg" width="68" height="90" alt="reply">
```

how can i tell the website to recognize it as a picture and display it ?

is it possible to extend this function to embed youtube video etc. ?

==================================================================

Added some scripts below, i guess this is the code that limiting output as text only.....

```
 function createRow(text) {
        var $row = $('<li class="list-group-item"></li>');
        $row.text(text);
        $chatlog.append($row);
      }
```

Update: i amended `$row.text(text);` to `$row.html(text);` , it can properly display html code now.

Comment: you can set dynamic src with jquery/javascript.

Comment: could give me the names of jquery packages so i can try to research? thanks

Comment: with jquery you can do simply `$('img').src('your image src')`

Comment: Where's the code that generates the given markup? As far as I see, there is no problem with the snippet you've shared

Answer (score 1):

you can use ParentNode.append() function to append new image element to your html. (documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append)

Example:

```
var yourImage = document.createElement("img");
yourImage.src = "some/dynamic/source.jpg"
document.body.append(yourImage);
```

Comment: do u mean i need to put this whole thing in the output like this?

"<script>var yourImage = document.createElement("img");
yourImage.src = "some/dynamic/source.jpg"
document.body.append(yourImage);</script>"

Comment: I mean this is a way to display dynamic <img src> on webpage. You just need to edit the "some/dynamic/source.jpg" to your image URL. Also, it is JavaScript code so yes it has to be wrapped in <script> tag

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, just try the following changes:

Add id attribute to your img tag:

```
<img src="path/reply.jpg" width="68" height="90" alt="reply" id="img1">
```

And in Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () 
 {
    $("#img1").attr({ "src": "img.jpg" });
 });
```